# c# Entity Framework - linq to entity query with subquery

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

If I have the following tables/entities:

Invoice
 - InvoiceId (PK)
 - InvoiceAmount

InvoicePayment
 - InvoicePaymentId (PK)
 - InvoiceId (FK)
 - PaymentAmount

How can I construct a Linq to Entity query that selects invoices with an outstanding amount - bearing in mind that the existence of a payment does not indicate that the invoice does not have an outstanding amount (i.e. partial payment are possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something along the lines of this

```
from i in invoices
where i.Payments.Sum(p=>p.PaymentAmount) < i.InvoiceAmount
select i;
```

Comment: Thanks @Luke McGregor, I was applying too much thought to it and trying to to something with .any() which isn't necessary.

Comment: Nah you definitally want a sum here, You can do the same as this in full fluent syntax but i think it looks readable like it is